# Can anyone explain this php code injection attack to me?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I've been receiving requests for unexpected urls on my server.

Specifically one for `/%70%68%70%70%61%74%68/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E`

This seems to be happening every few hours.

I ran the url through http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ and it comes out as:

> phppath/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n

What is the attacker trying to do here?

Comment: 5 seconds on google: http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/06/plesk-0-day-remote-vulnerability-in-the-wild.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hacking attempt


Answer (score 11, accepted):

Attacker is trying to make use of [CVE-2012-1823](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-1823), this only applies if your PHP is used in CGI mode (mod_php is not vulnerable to this).

Using `-d` parameter injection to PHP binary attacker disables various protection mechanisms your PHP might have in place and executes PHP code directly by using `auto_prepend_file` (automatically executes PHP code before processing any PHP file), while `php://input` is a stream of POST request data.

Unless your web server logging is custom you probably won't find out what attacker had in the POST request (POST data are not being logged normally).

Check your PHP, eg. using a script like this:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

PHP version is on the first line, compare that to CVE definition.
If you're using a vulnerable version, update it ASAP, also look for **Server API** line there, if it does not contain something with CGI you should be safe for the moment, but using an obsolete PHP version is never good.

Answer (score 3):

attacker is try to update your php configuration file(php.ini)
allow_url_include,safe_mode are different php configuration settings which are important for security, so they are disabled by default